# Trouble importing simplegui

Tags: python, python-2.7, codeskulptor

I installed PyDev in Eclipse to run Python programs, but I’m facing trouble importing `simplegui`. It is showing me this error:

> ```
> import simplegui
> ```
>
> `ImportError`: No module named `simplegui`

My installed PyDev version is 2.7.1.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SimpleGUICS2Pygame](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUICS2Pygame).
Just change
**import simplegui**
by
**import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui**
in your CodeSkulptor program and run it in standard Python

Answer (score 4):

Did you learn Python using CodeSkulptor?
simplegui is a custom module for CodeSkulptor, meaning that it is only available in CodeSkulptor.

More information [here](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#).

Comment: [Porting from CodeSkulptor to PyGame](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/CS_to_PyGame.html)

Comment: You can use [SimpleGUICS2Pygame](http://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.org/). It's a implementation of SimpleGUI to standard Python.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a Mac, when I installed `simplegui` off of the Python website, I had to import it as:

```
import simpleguitk
```

I also downloaded it through terminal with the command:

```
sudo pip install SimpleGUITk
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Does not work well but it is the correct import.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, download simplegui.zip form http://florian-berger.de/en/software/simplegui.

```
unzip simplegui-x.x.x.zip
cd simplegui-x.x.x
python setup.py install
```

Replace `x.x.x` with version number. You might want to run the last step with sudo rights.

Comment: C:\Temp\Python>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    import simplegui
  File "C:\Temp\Python\simplegui.py", line 31, in <module>
    import Tkinter
ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'

Comment: This simplegui is a Python package which has the same name as SimpleGUI of CodeSkulptor, but it is totally something else.

[SimpleGUICS2Pygame](http://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.org/) is a reimplementation of SimpleGUI to standard Python.