# SimpleGUI on IDLE

Tags: python, pysimplegui, codeskulptor

I have managed to develop a game using the simplegui module and am able to run it on CodeSkulptor, but when I try running it on IDLE, it displays that the module simplegui is not found. I'm not really getting how to download the module on my system and am unable to find any solution on Google. Is there any way I can get simplegui, or is it an outdated module(I'm finding many websites explaining how to download PySimpleGUI and Tkinter but can't find simplegui)?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815722/trouble-importing-simplegui

Comment: @Konqui both the links r the same

Answer (score 0):

Check this question:
[How to integrate SimpleGUI with Python 2.7 and 3.0 shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387770/how-to-integrate-simplegui-with-python-2-7-and-3-0-shell)

You can use:

```
import simpleguitk as simplegui
```